# How do you bind a DataRow to a TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have Window. Window.DataContext = DataRow.

and i have TextBlock.

I need to bind DataRow.Array[0] to the Text property of a TextBlock.

how do I do it?

edit:

```
<Window x:Class="Client.payment.CheckMore"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" Loaded="Window_Loaded" x:Name="p_this">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="p_idCheck" Text="{Binding Path=Array[0]}"/>
            </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

in code: this.DataContext = dateRow.Rows[0];

Comment: Does any other binding work??

I mean you set datacontext after the control was created and, i assume, rendered. try to do it before or raise canexecutechanged event..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Property you're looking for is probably ItemArray. You can bind to it like this, the following ways will give you the same result (if the first Column is named Column1).

- The first example binds to the first item in ItemArray
- The second example binds to the value of the first Column
- The third example binds to the value of the Column named Column1. This is the recommended approach since it will still work even if your Columns change order.

Xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="p_idCheck"
               Text="{Binding Path=ItemArray[0]}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="p_idCheck2"
               Text="{Binding Path=[0]}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="p_idCheck3"
               Text="{Binding Path=[Column1]}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind example

```
private DataSet m_dataSet = null;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_dataSet = new DataSet();

    DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable("Table1");
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
    m_dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable1);

    DataRow dataRow1 = dataTable1.NewRow();
    dataRow1["Column1"] = "Column1Value";
    dataTable1.Rows.Add(dataRow1);

    this.DataContext = dataRow1;            
}
```

Comment: Very good answer. this answer helped me for creating dynamic form with Binding in wpf .

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Array[0]}" ...
```

works fine if `Array` is  public property.